# react-id-swiper is not working with dynamic cards

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, swiper.js

I have a reactJS cards component which fetches data from strapi and then I am implementing react-id-swiper with the dynamic cards which are built on the go. Now react-id-swiper is working fine if I hardcode the cards. But is not working with the logic. I am pasting the code for the cards.

```
`import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './desktop-card.module.css';
import Swiper from 'react-id-swiper';
import 'swiper/css/swiper.css';



const params = {
    direction: 'horizontal',
    loop: true,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    mousewheel: true,
    autoPlay: {
        delay: 2000
    }
}

const Cards = props => {
    const singleCard = props.cardsData.map((card, index) => {
        return (
            <React.Fragment key={index}>
                <div className="scene scene--card swiper-slide">
                    <div className="mojo-card d-flex flex-column" style={{backgroundColor:card.backgroundColor}}>
                        <h3 className="heading py-4 px-4">{card.heading}</h3>
                        <p className="card-content px-4">{card.content}</p>
                        <div className="mojo-card__img card-img-data">
                            <img alt={'image'+card.id}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    });
    return <React.Fragment>{singleCard}</React.Fragment>
}

class DeskTopCards extends Component {
    render() {   
        const { cardsData } = this.props;
        if(!this.props) return null;
        return ( 
            <Swiper {...params}>
                <Cards cardsData={cardsData}/>
            </Swiper>
        )
    }
}

export default DeskTopCards;

`
```

Please help. I am new to ReactJS.

Here is the parent components code. The cardsData is not empty.

````
```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import DesktopCards from './Desktop-card/desktop-card';

class CardContainer extends React.Component {
    state = {
        data: []
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const url = '';// strapi url

        fetch(url)
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(result => {
                this.setState({
                    data: result
                });
            });
    }

    render() {
        const { data } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="col-lg-7 col-md-7 px-0 box d-flex w-100 flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center right-side-scroll">
                   <DesktopCards cardsData={data}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CardContainer;
```
````

Comment: This works for me. Are you passing the cardsData prop to DesktopCards? Can you paste your other code where you used the DesktopCards?

Comment: Are you sure that cardsData actually has a value and is not always null?

Comment: I have added the parents component code. cardsData has value.

Comment: Still works for me. What about desktop-card.module.css? Can you post that?

Comment: Swiper works. But, few options like autoplay, loop are not working.

Answer (score 3):

It might be too late but I stumbled on this as well.
The trick is in the documentation but it's quite easy to miss.
[Image from the documentation on github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSegZ.png)
Which means that for any custom component you need to wrap it up with an html element such as div.
So for example:

```
<Swiper>
 <div><Card1/></div>
 <div><Card2/></div>
 <div><Card3/></div> 
</Swiper>
```

Kind of sucks to do this but if it's necessary for you to use the library, that should do it.

Comment: It sounds weird, but it does the trick! I spent hours investigating the problem. Thank you buddy!

Answer (score 1):

I was trying examples from https://react-id-swiper.ashernguyen.site/ which is not working fine on my local even i gone through their code in sandbox which works there.

After a some analysis i suspected some css were missed in swiper 6.1.2, Hence I  degraded swiper version to 5.3.8

That works for me, Tried few examples It's working fine on my machine.

package.json

```
"react-id-swiper" : "^4.0.0",
"swiper" : "5.3.8"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess react-id-swiper doesn't work correctly with `<React.Fragment>`.
remove `<React.Fragment>` from your code and test it again.
I had this problem with react-id-swiper when I removed , fixed my problem.